# Nintex Workflow 2007 - global settings / variables

Tags: workflow, nintex-workflow

**The problem:**
When we create a workflow on UAT/Stage environment we need to import it to Production environment. Then we need to change the environment URLs (Web Service calls and such) and email addresses.

**Is it possible:**
To store URLs and emails in some global configuration where the Nintex Workflow would pick it up so whenever we deploy the workflow again to production we wouldn't need to go to each step and edit its settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an email from Nintex Support:

> Dear Jakub,
>
> Thank you for your e-mail.
>
> The only suggestion I have is to use Workflow Constants. You can
>   configure workflow constants in Central Administration > Application
>   Management > Manage Workflow Constants.
>
> In your workflow you use a lookup reference which points to the
>   appropriate workflow constant. As long as the Workflow constant name
>   is the same in both environments the workflow will pick it up but the
>   Workflow constant will contain the relevant URL for the environment.
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> Kind Regards
>
> Simon Muntz Software Support Engineer - Team Lead Nintex Workflow for
>   Everyone®   |   nintex.com

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use a list on your site as a configuration settings table. Set up a list of name/value pairs, then at runtime your workflow can query the list by name and retrieve the required value.